# Can Katsuki Bakugo fly as much as he wants with his explosion quirk?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My Hero Academia, we see several times Bakugo using his explosion quirk to lift himself to mid-air and fly to increase his speed. How much can he uses this technique to fly? Can he fly as much as he wants or is he limited to fly a few metres above the ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember this being elaborated in the manga, but since it is very serious of the mechanics of the quirks, we can find out ourselves. I'll use this [page](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Katsuki_Bakugo) as reference.

> Katsuki's Quirk allows him to sweat nitroglycerin from his palms and detonate it at will to create explosions.

So as long as he sweats, he can fly. This effect is in fact achieved by being on the right side of the shock wave of the explosion. However:

> These explosions, especially when used repeatedly in rapid succession, were actually shown to have a negative impact on Katsuki's arms.

So there is a limit.

To actually fly and not just "jump" midair, he would need to navigate the explosions constantly, adjusting their strength and also needing a really big amount stored if he wants to fly long distances, which on the other hand he needs to carry.

So if Bakugo wanted to fly, think of him as an Iron Man without repulsors in his shoes (allowing him only to navigate and accelerate/decelerate with the hands) on short fuel with every second of the repulsors being on taking a burden on his arms. Not really flying.

Answer (score 2):

**Tl;Dr** Bakugo isn't flying at all. He is jumping and augmenting himself using his Explosion quirk. There is no actual flying involved, though he may seem to be floating (much like Midoriya) in the slowmos.

We see him do the exact same thing multiple times throughout the anime/manga.

- He does this when he sent threw the baseball flying or the sprint/long jump in the Quick Apprehension Test.

[image]
[image]

- He shows more adaptability with his precision and control by jumping and changing directions during the Trial Battle

[image]

- The main proof his "inability" to fly while jumping really high comes during the Sports Festival. Cero had to use tape to control his dissent. If he could maneuver himself, Cero wouldn't have needed to help.

[image]
[image]

- The most lengthy and continuous use of his explosion is the so called "Special Move" used by Bakugo using his explosions to rotate while propelling himself like a bullet, the Howitzer Blast seen in finals vs Todoroki

[image]

Comment: His inability to maneuver shows a lack of ability, but not the impossibility to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

he can fly but crudely. He's moving through the air without having to touch the ground so I suppose it counts. His limit would be how much he can sweat and how long he can endure his own explosions. Elevation-wise,he has no real limits there. He's flown all the way up to catch Kirishima's hand which was well above some multistory buildings. He's also flown low like in the Quirk Apprehension Exam.